# Set value to variable within async block

Tags: node.js

Following is a part of the nodejs script.

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);


fs.writeFile( filepath, dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("note")[i].textContent, function(err) {
            if(err) { return console.log(err); }
});

const text_content = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("note")[i].textContent ; 

async function exec_python3() {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(`bash -c 'python3 ${filepath}'`);
  text_content = stdout ; 
}

exec_python3() ;
```

`dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("note")[i].textContent` is a jsdom object.

What I want to do is replace content in `dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("note")[i].textContent` with stdout of executed Python3. 
For example, currently value of `dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("note")[i].textContent` is `print("foo")` and the value will be `foo` after `exec_python3() ;`.

But above script occurs error `Assignment to constant variable.`. I have no idea what I have to do, any idea? thanks.

Comment: You should probably start by reading up on what `const` means

Comment: Which part of `error: Assignment to constant variable` do you not understand?   You cannot assign a value to a variable declared with `const` after the declaration.  Use `let` when you declare the variable if you want to be able to assign to it later.  I tend to think this isn't your real issue, but the point of the question is hard to follow so I commented on the error you report.

Comment: I knew that. but If you use `let` to define the statement you'll get `TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined` error. That made me confuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change `dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("note")[i].textContent` then you need to change **that**.

Copying its value to a variable and then changing the value of that variable isn't going to touch `dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("note")[i].textContent`.

So:

```
dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("note")[i].textContent = stdout;
```

---

As for your error, while fixing it won't fix your problem, the *entire* point of using `const` is that you set it once and then can't change it. Use `let` if you want a variable you can change.

Comment: If you just type the above one within `async function exec_python3()`, you'll get ` TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined` error. That's why I have added a const line.

Comment: @k23j4 — there's no enough information in the question to determine why it would be defined when you read from it but not when you want to write to it. Presumably, `i` has changed. And presumably, the solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example